# I need a Zend Framework start up guide PDF file

Tags: zend-framework

I need a Zend Framework start up guide PDF file.
http://www.mikaelkael.fr/Zend-Framework-1-8-x-documentation.html

this is an advanced level..but i need a beginners level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rob Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23060/rob-allen) has written and excellent [introduction to Zend Framework 1.8](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) which is also [available as a PDF](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

i think the best thing to do is to take a php MVC tutorial first and then look into ZEND, it would be much more easier.